# iphone prevent autorotation but only when keyboard is showing

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to prevent auto-rotation from a view controller when the keyboard is showing? 
I don't want to capture the notifications and handle all drawing by hand if possible.

Edit:I found that the root view controller in the chain was preventing the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: message from coming down the pipe. Once it was taken away at the root view controller level and left to the sub-view controllers to handle it worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Does the editing use a UITextField? If so, have you tried using the UITextFieldDelegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing: as a place to modify a flag referenced by shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: ?